# GLM perspective matrix ruins rendering

Tags: c++, graphics, glsl, vulkan, glm-math

I created a projection matrix for Vulkan renderer using GLM, but after multiplying it with vertex itself in vertex shader, nothing renders. I have defined GLM_FORCE_RADIANS and GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE (to be fine, I tried without both of these, or without one of these). Also I tried to pass fovy param as degrees or radians, but it didn't help. In addition, I noticed that orthographic matrix works just fine! Here's my code of vertex shader, matrix creation itself and front face is CCW (if it can help), depth testing disabled (didn't implement that yet):

Projection matrix creation:

```
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 16.0f / 9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::rotate(model, (float)glfwGetTime() * 30, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

layout(push_constant) uniform MVP {
   mat4 VP;
   mat4 Transform;
} matrices;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 Color;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = matrices.VP * matrices.Transform * vec4(aPos, 
   1.0f, 1.0f);
   Color = vec4(aColor, 1.0f);
}
```

The way I include GLM:

```
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 just tried that, didn't work. I tried that with and without GLM_FORCE_RADIANS and `GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE` is defined before glm includes.

Comment: I'm trying to render 2D quad in 3D space with proper perspective rotation / transformation etc. It is *initial* value of vertex's Z coordinate, which is being modified right after multiplication by model and projection matrix.

Comment: your transformation is backwards

Comment: should be P * V * M in opengl.   OpenGL multiplies left to right, -- directx multiplies right to left

Comment: If your Model / View matrix was identity -- then it would have worked correctly, -- as P * V * M = P in that case

Comment: but instead you are doing crazy stuff after projection is done. --

Comment: I tried both variants but still no result. Consider that orthographic matrix works fine, even though I multiply it in exact same way. And I'm using Vulkan, so it should be OpenGL-like multiplication - P * V * M.

Comment: P * V * M is correct -- don't use the other one -- soemthing else is broken if that is being used.

Comment: Is your model being clipped?

Comment: Is DepthTest enabled?

Comment: You'd really need to put your full code out with minimal ways to reproduce the problem for us to debug it

Comment: Depth test is not enabled, but I have literally no geometry drawn except that 2D quad.

Comment: how was your camera View constructed.

Comment: For now it is just identity matrix. I tried to "move" camera's Z coordinate from -25.0f to 25.0f, but no result (was thinking that something is being clipped, so I can't see anything, but that's not it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The "problem" was that projection and perspective division maps the [-near, -far] range to [-1, 1], which lead to flipping Z coordinate. Meanwhile I had Z coordinate as 10.0f, it was actually behing the camera.
Solution was setting up Z coordinate value as -10.0f, which will be flipped to 10.0f after projection.

Answer (score 0):

From `glm::perspective`:

> **fovy**  Expressed in radians if GLM_FORCE_RADIANS is defined or degrees otherwise.

You're defining `GLM_FORCE_RADIANS`, that means you should pass radians as value to `glm::perspective`. The value in your example (`45.0f`) looks like degrees, but i could be wrong.

Comment: It is not necessary to define `GLM_FORCE_RADIANS` at all. The newer glm-math versions always use radiant.

Comment: Tried to pass `fovy` argment as `glm::radians(45.0f)` but still no result. Tried also passing it as raw float value or `glm::degrees(45.0f)` and all that with and without `GLM_FORCE_RADIANS`. No result, I can see only clear color on screen.